# Diferenças entre __name__ e __qualname__

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflexão

No Python funções/métodos e classes possuem dois atributos que em seu uso mais "básico" parecem fazer exatamente a mesma coisa, são eles: `__name__` e `__qualname__`, veja:

```
def fn(): 
    pass


class C(object):
    pass


>>> fn.__name__
"fn"
>>> fn.__qualname__
"fn"
>>> C.__name__
"C"
>>> C.__qualname__
"C"
```

Qual a diferença entre `__name__` e `__qualname__`?

Comment: Útil: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É exatamente a mesma coisa no uso básico. No exemplo citado não muda. Mas quando você tem classes ou funções aninhadas aí muda. Usando um exemplo mais complexo veja que só a classe ou função de maior nível que está em *namespace* global produz o mesmo resultado, as demais mudam e só `__qualname__` produz um caminho completo do nome, o chamado *fully qualified name*. `__name__` só dá o nome básico sem "sobrenome", o que pode ser ambíguo quando o elemento do código está aninhado.

```
class C:
   def f(): pass
   class D:
     def g(): pass
 
print(C.__qualname__)
print(C.f.__qualname__)
print(C.D.__qualname__)
print(C.D.g.__qualname__)
 
def f():
   def g(): pass
   return g
 
print(f.__qualname__)
print(f().__qualname__)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Vn87zk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oxxdiagw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Introspection.py).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.